# java.net.MalformedURLException java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, servlets

I keep getting this error and I really dont know why. I have tried different URLs but I still get the same error.

**java.net.MalformedURLException
    java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)**

```
public class ProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {

private String PostUrl = "http://localhost:8080/myProxy/myServlet";

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ProxyServlet() {
    super();
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("Parameters retreived...");
    // map parameters to properties in config file and set response
    Map();
    }

private void Map() throws IOException{


        String urlParameters = "topic="+topic+"&item="+item+"&period="+period+";
        URL url = new URL(PostUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("Connection made to " + PostUrl);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

        OutputStream out = null;

        try{
            System.out.println("Writing data to output stream...");
            out = conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(urlParameters.getBytes());
            out.close();
            System.out.println("All done!!!");
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't compile.

Your URL is invalid. Can't assume it is as shown because of above.

Also you must URLEncode the parameter names and values.

Comment: Thanks. I have URLEncoded the parameters. Why do you think the URL is invalid? I am pretty sure the URL exists. Even if I try something like [http://yahoo.com](http://yahoo.com), I still get the same error.

Comment: @user1192724 It's invalid because the exception says so. Malformed, not just non-existent. Check it carefully.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that I was modifying the url variable somewhere else in my code and was setting it to null. Fixed that and it works perfectly. Thanks!